# MVC: How do i declare the name value using DropDownListFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following dropdownlist in mvc

```
 <%= Html.DropDownListFor(c => c.Address.Id, new SelectList(Model.Addresses, "id", "Name", Model.Address.Id), "-- New Address --", new { @name = "[" + orderItemAddressCount + "].AddressId" })%>
```

I'm trying to overwrite the name value on the dropdownlist.

this is the markup i get

```
 <select id="Address_Id" name="Address.Id"><option value="">-- New Address --</option>
```

This is the markup i want

```
 <select id="Address_Id" name="[0].AddressId"><option value="">-- New Address --</option>
```

How do i declare the name value using DropDownListFor?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot override the name generated by the `DropDownListFor` method. It is strongly typed and the name is based on the lambda you are passing as argument. If you want to override the name of the generated select the way you want you will have to either write your own extension method or use the non-strongly typed `DropDownList` method:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList(
    "[0].AddressId", 
    new SelectList(Model.Addresses, "id", "Name", Model.Address.Id), 
    "-- New Address --") 
%>
```

But why would you want to do this anyway? Aren't you binding to the same ViewModel when you submit the form?

Comment: great thanks darin, all sorted i used HTML.DropDownList. I was binding to a collection of addresses, so i needed to added the index. [0].AddressId. thanks again.

Comment: "why would you want to do this anyway?" We have editor templates nested inside partial views, so the default names are wrong (they are relative to the partial view). We could skip the partial view step, but then we end up duplicating a lot of code in every editor template (we have several templates because display of a portion of each element changes drastically based on properties).

Answer (score 4):

You can override the name on an Html.DropDownListFor by using a capital N in Name. See this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18344087