# Can I change the html name generated by Html.DropDownListFor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

IDI am using the following code to create a drop down list:

```
 @for (var index = 0; index < Model.AdminSummaries.Count(); index++) 
            { 
            <div class="rep_tr0"> 
                <div class="rep_td0"> 
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.AdminSummaries[index].Status, AdminStatusReference.GetAdminStatusOptions()) 
                </div>
```

The code creates the following:

```
<select id="AdminSummaries_2__Status" name="AdminSummaries[2].Status">
   <option value="1">Released</option>
   <option value="2">Review</option>
   <option value="3">New</option>
</select> 
<select id="AdminSummaries_3__Status" name="AdminSummaries[3].Status">
   <option value="1">Released</option>
   <option value="2">Review</option>
   <option value="3">New</option>
</select>
```

Is there any way that I could change it so that it creates a **ID** of "Status_2", "Status_3" etc.

Answer (score 85):

As @Anar said in the comments;

> Actually, you can change the name attribute the same way as id, but instead of "name", use "Name". Surprisingly it works.

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.AdminSummaries[index].Status, 
AdminStatusReference.GetAdminStatusOptions(), 
new { id = string.Format("Status_{0}",index ), Name = "GiveName" });
```

Comment: I've found that this just adds a property "Name" and does not set the property "name"

Comment: Doesn't work as described, at least not in MVC4. Behaviour reported by @nuander is the same for me.

Comment: checked just now and it works for me just fine and olso in MVC4

Comment: Checked on mvc5 - wokrs fo me!

Comment: @Laguna Works, but isn't documented, so it's liable to change... I'm afraid to use this "feature" unless someone has an official reference?

Comment: Adding  a capital "Name" attribute did NOT work for me.  I just ended up with "name" and "Name" attributes.

Comment: I just tested this too on MVC4, and I can report the following behavour: Looking at the generated source code, both `Name=""` and `name=""` are set. Chrome dev tools report only the first one to be set (which is my custom name). So I'm not sure if this is totally cross-browser compatible. I'll go the plain old way of outputting my dropdown manually :)

Comment: Still working in MVC5.2.9! Nice one!

Answer (score 13):

Sometimes the HTML helpers don't HELP.  DropDownListFor coding can get complicated real fast and in the end it's just rendering HTML so sometimes it's better to go old school

```
<select name="myname" class="dropdownlist" id="myid">
    @foreach (SelectListItem item in Model.SomeSelectList) {
        if (item.Value ==  Model.theValue) {
            <option value="@(item.Value)" selected="selected">@item.Text</option>
        } else {
            <option value="@(item.Value)">@item.Text</option>
        }
    }
</select>
```

Comment: Agreed - it is very easy to waste a lot of time trying to get the helpers to do what you want and often times it is just much quicker to go back to basics.

Answer (score 13):

For those wondering why this doesn't work, the whole thing is case sensitive and need an @ in front of it...

so, this works:

```
new { @id = "myID", @Name = "myName", @Value = "myValue", @class = "form-control", @onchange = "javascript:DoSomething(this.value);" }
```

And this doesn't (mind the lowercase 'n' in `@name`)

```
new { @id = "myID", @name = "myName", @Value = "myValue", @class = "form-control", @onchange = "javascript:DoSomething(this.value);" }
```

Comment: Thank you, you helped me a lot.

Comment: That doesn't work for me. using .NET Core 3.1. But I can add other attributes using this. "name" in my source always seems to be automatically derived from the model.

Answer (score 6):

You can set/change the ID just like any HTML attribute (but not name I've found).

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.AdminSummaries[index].Status, AdminStatusReference.GetAdminStatusOptions(), new { id = string.Format("Status_{0}",index ) });
```

Comment: Looks like internally the code to set the name property is invoked after adding all other HTML attributes and uses the replaceExisting flag to override any that you've set:

`tagBuilder.MergeAttributes(htmlAttributes);
 tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("name", fullName, true /* replaceExisting */);`

Comment: Yea, I noticed that too. As I mentioned in my answer, ID can be changed via this method, name cannot. You might want to change your question, it specifies "ID" in the text of the question.

Comment: @core24 Actually, you can change the name attribute the same way as id, but instead of name, use Name. Surprisingly it works.

Comment: @anarkhalilov, that's amazing. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Just use "Name" instead of "name" and it works.

```
@Html.DropDownList("ClassID", null, "Select Class", htmlAttributes: new { id = _id, Name =_id, @class = "form-control" })
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to change From DropDownListFor To DropDownList. Than you can change name easily.

```
@Html.DropDownList("YourName", SelectList, new { @id = "YourId", @class = "YourClass" })
```

Hope It will work.

Answer (score 2):

ID can be changed as described by @Arbiter. However, if you want to change the name, then I think you need to use `@Html.DropDownList` rather than `@Html.DropDownListFor`. This loses you any benefits of having the strong typing for the property element, but as just changing IDs means you can't access the values in a meaningful way if looking at the `Request.Form` response, this may be an acceptable workaround for you.

Comment: I agree that one should use DropDownList instead of DropDownListFor. This is helpful in my case because I have a view with an array of fields, which all have a "Value" and "ID" property. Obviously, I don't want all the fields to have the name "Value"; rather, I want each input element to store the Value for each field, but use the unique ID for the input name. In this scenario, the strongly-typed automatic binding to the model field is lost, and instead I just read the uniquely named values from the posted form data and assign their value to the model field with the corresponding id.

Comment: Another benefit of using the DropDownList even over plain HTML, is that you can use dot notation in your field id's such as "Images.AppBackground", and the dot will automatically be replaced with an underscore in the select's ID attribute, but not in the Name attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks .. it work...adding .Name change the name of the html password attribute

```
      @Html.PasswordFor(Function(model) model.password, New With {.Autocomplete = "off", .Name = "oldpassword", .id = "oldpassword", .value = Model.password, .readonly = True})
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this issue is to replace the id and name after DropDownListFor() with a html helper extension method.

```
        public static MvcHtmlString ReplaceIdAndName(this MvcHtmlString htmlSource, string name)
    {
        MvcHtmlString result;
        if (name == null)
            result = htmlSource;
        else
        {
            string id = name.Replace("[", "_").Replace("]", "_").Replace(".", "_");  // HTML ids cannot have []. so MVC convention replaces with _
            XDocument html = XDocument.Parse(htmlSource.ToHtmlString());
            html.Elements().Select(e => e.Attribute("id")).FirstOrDefault().SetValue(id);
            html.Elements().Select(e => e.Attribute("name")).FirstOrDefault().SetValue(name);
            result = MvcHtmlString.Create(html.ToString());
        }
        return result;
    }


DropDownListFor(...).ReplaceIdAndName("myclass[1].myprop");
```